# CSS transition not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

this is my first question i need help with my project site... i want to make image move up so i have a nice slide in effect but on hover i still have fast transition, how can i fix that

```
<div id="nav_bar_menu">
    <li class="pocetna" id="nav_bar_menu_bars"><a id="nav_bar_a" href="#" ></a></li>
    <li class="usluge" id="nav_bar_menu_bars"><a id="nav_bar_a" href="#" ></a></li>
    <li class="projekti" id="nav_bar_menu_bars"><a id="nav_bar_a" href="#" ></a></li>
    <li class="kontakt" id="nav_bar_menu_bars"><a id="nav_bar_a" href="#" ></a></li>
</div><!-- Menu -->
```

here is the css

```
#nav_bar_menu {
    height: 38px;
    width: 580px;
    background-color: #0F6;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    margin-top: 93px;
    overflow:hidden;

}
#nav_bar_menu_bars {
    height: 78px;
    width: 131px;
    margin-right: 14px;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}
#nav_bar_a {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 131px;
    height:76px;
    float: left;
}

.pocetna {
    background-image: url(../Images/images/nav_bar_pictures_01.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center top;
 }

.usluge {
    background-image: url(../Images/images/nav_bar_pictures_01.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center top;
 }

.projekti {
    background-image: url(../Images/images/nav_bar_pictures_01.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center top;
 }

.kontakt {
    background-image: url(../Images/images/nav_bar_pictures_01.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center top;
 }
.pocetna:hover {
    position:relative;
    top:-38px;
}
.usluge:hover {
    position:relative;
    top:-38px;
}
.projekti:hover {
    position:relative;
    top:-38px;
}
.kontakt:hover {
    position:relative;
    top:-38px;
}
```

i tryed with transition but its not making changes... please help me
or maybe some javascript that will make it animate..

Comment: *"CSS transition not working".* There is nothing that indicates there is one.

Comment: it will not work as you are using sprites for your images. you would need to add an empty span to grab the 'image on hover' with a transition delay. and then on the span:hover you apply the change. I've had to do something similiar for my project. Have a read at http://css-tricks.com/fade-image-within-sprite/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link to a page that documents the CSS transition property... http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp
Have a look at that.

What I am inferring is the following: You want the following classes, on hover, to move up along the Y-Axis: .pocetna, .usluge, .projekti, .kontakt. This is why you've set the attribute top: -38px; for these classes with the :hover pseudo selector. To make this happen smoothly with a transition you need the following code...

```
 .pocetna, .usluge, .projekti, .kontakt {
    background-image: url(../Images/images/nav_bar_pictures_01.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center top;
    -moz-transition: top 2s;
    -webkit-transition: top 2s;
    -o-transition: top 2s;
    transition: top 2s;
 }


.pocetna:hover {
    position:relative;
    top:-38px;
}
.usluge:hover {
    position:relative;
    top:-38px;
}
.projekti:hover {
    position:relative;
    top:-38px;
}
.kontakt:hover {
    position:relative;
    top:-38px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much... its works on google chrome but for some reason it does not work of firefox. Can you tell me how can i make it move back slowly when i move my hover mouse ? to make it move back in 0.5s?

Comment: the -moz prefix should take care of it in Firefox... This is only necessary if you are running a version of Firefox earlier than version 15. To make it transition back, you probably just need to position the class... So setting position:relative and top:0 for the classes without the hover psuedo selector should do it.